# Is it possible to show warnings instead of errors on ALL of eslint rules?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, eslint, eslintrc, standardjs

As the title says, would it be possible for eslint to show warnings instead of errors on ALL of the rules? I'm using Standard JS, if that information is relevant.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to just show warnings and suppress the errors? Or do you want the errors to be treated as warnings and shown as such?

Comment: I want the errors to be treated as warnings and shown as such.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I think there's no out-of-the-box option right now, but maybe you could use a plugin to achieve that:
[Eslint plugin only warn](https://github.com/bfanger/eslint-plugin-only-warn)

Or set all the rules as warning instead of errors.

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to not work with the newest version of eslint (v6). It works well for v5, though.

Comment: I can confirm it works with `eslint: 7.2.0`, when i tried. Thank the lord for these plugin makers. 

It fills me with immediate magma temperature RAGE! When in the middle of a complex bug and everything fails because there's a space at the end of the line or one of your imports has not yet been used. 

It grinds my gears!! :D

Comment: The opposite plugin also exists: [eslint-plugin-only-error](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/eslint-plugin-only-error).

Comment: Works perfect with `7.32.0`

Comment: The only issue with eslint-plugin-only-warn is that actual errors like undefined variables appear as warnings, and it's not possible to change that

Comment: @Jasper it's possible to allow some errors with this fork: https://github.com/aminya/eslint-plugin-only-warn

Answer (score 50):

Following [es-lint-plugin-prettier readme](https://github.com/prettier/eslint-plugin-prettier), edit your `.eslintrc.json` and put a specific rule for `prettier`:

```
"rules": {
  // maybe your other rules...

  "prettier/prettier": "warn"
}
```

Then, `prettier` rules will be issued as warnings instead of errors.

Not sure of all the side effects, but it seems to work ok for my project, where I also use `@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin`, `@typescript-eslint/parser`, `eslint-config-prettier` and `eslint-plugin-prettier`.

If it helps, my `extends` config in `.eslintrc.json`:

```
"extends": [
  "eslint:recommended",
  "plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended",
  "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
  "prettier/@typescript-eslint",
  "plugin:prettier/recommended"
],
```

Comment: This answer is great if you're using prettier & eslint (I am), though not sure the OP is.

Comment: Exactly what I was after!

Comment: Or use `"prettier/prettier": process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "error" : "warn"` to warn in dev, but fail in production :)

Answer (score 3):

If you're only interested in VSCode output, you can achieve this with a single setting:

```json
"eslint.rules.customizations": [
  { "rule": "*", "severity": "warn" }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did was overwrite the rules that I want to only show warnings.  You can do it in .eslitrc.cjs.  Here is what I have in mine:

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: { browser: true, es2020: true },
  extends: [
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'plugin:react/jsx-runtime',
    'plugin:react-hooks/recommended',
  ],
  ignorePatterns: ['dist', '.eslintrc.cjs'],
  parserOptions: { ecmaVersion: 'latest', sourceType: 'module', parser: "@babel/eslint-parser" },
  settings: { react: { version: '18.2' } },
  plugins: ['react-refresh'],
  rules: {
    'react-refresh/only-export-components': [
      'warn',
      { allowConstantExport: true },
    ],
    'no-unused-vars':['warn'],
    'react/jsx-key':['warn'],
    'react/no-unescaped-entities':['warn'],
    'react/prop-types':['warn'],
    'no-undef':['warn']
  },
}
```

For any problem that comes up as an error that is constantly in your way, you can just add it to the rules here to overwrite it.  Then you can continue coding and deal with the problems at your leisure.

Answer (score -2):

You can create an `.eslintrc` file with all the rules set to `"warn"`

If you already have an eslintrc file you can use that, or extend from a rules file such as the one [here](https://gist.github.com/cletusw/e01a85e399ab563b1236). In this one, all the rules are set to `0` (disabled). You can modify specific ones or all of them and set them to `1` (or `"warn"`)

Comment: this is very tedious