# change all eslint errors to warning instead of error using .eslintrc.js

Tags: eslint, eslintrc

Is there a way to change all eslint errors to warnings using eslintrc.js file?

I just hate it at the moment, especially when it stops the entire program because I added an extra space.

I was wondering is there a way to turn all errors off and let prettier handle the rearranging of the code?

P.S. I am using vscode as the IDE and

I know about the comment thingy at the beginning of the code. It does not work on a vue or nuxt project

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50705508/is-it-possible-to-show-warnings-instead-of-errors-on-all-of-eslint-rules

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you're using the [ESLint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint) extension, you can customize the severity of ESLint rules using the setting `eslint.rules.customizations`.

For example, if you add the following snippet to your `.vscode/settings.json`, all ESLint errors will be shown as warnings in VSCode.

```json
"eslint.rules.customizations": [
  { "rule": "*", "severity": "warn" }
]
```

Comment: "eslint.rules.customizations": [
    { "rule": "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars", "severity": "warn" }
  ],