# I want to run a project with ES-Lint warnings

Tags: javascript, eslint

I am studying react with this tutorial. https://github.com/ayush221b/MarioPlan-react-redux-firebase-app

I tried to add es-lint to my project.
After installing
I restarted my project by yarn start
Many errors happened. Failed to compiler.
The project does not start anymore.
I wanted to develop the project with linter suggestions..
What should I do?
I am looking for a way to build project without fixing ESlint-warings for now.
Are there any settings to resume the project?

[image]

Comment: You can modify the eslint config in `package.json` to change these to warnings. I _think_ you could also just remove the config as well.

Comment: I think this what you are looking for. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64518226/my-create-react-app-is-failing-to-compile-due-to-eslint-error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to show warnings instead of errors on ALL of eslint rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50705508/is-it-possible-to-show-warnings-instead-of-errors-on-all-of-eslint-rules)

Comment: I tied this
  "scripts": {
    "start": "CI=false react-scripts start",
    "build": "CI=false react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }, in package.json but it still doesn't work

Comment: Eslint plugin only warn!??? That is exactly what I have wanted ! Thankss